# SSL (TLS) Error on Chome ONLY - this page includes other resources which are not secure

Tags: ssl, chrome-browser

I have a TLS Geotrust certificate installed. All browsers except for Chrome confirm the secure connection. On Chrome - it shows a triangle over the padlock and after you click on it - it says:

The identity of this website has been verified by Geotrust SSL CA...

BUT

underneath it says this:

"Your connection to www.example.com is encrypted with a 128-bit encryption. **However, this page includes other resources which are not secure.** These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, and can be modified by an attacker to change the look of the page.

This connection uses TLS 1.0

WHEN I PRESS THE CTRL+SHIFT+J shortcut - IT SAYS THE FOLLOWING:

**The page at 'https://www.EXAMPLE.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/' was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at 'http://www.EXAMPLE.com/index.php/catalogsearch/result/': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.**

I do NOT have any images other than the ones supplied by Magento (the Error does not even talk about any images)

Please help!

Thank you, thank you, thank you,

Allysin

Comment: Looks like an extension way be doing a ajax request or something else to the search results page, a bit odd.